# g:message multiple argument passing

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have 3 values coming from model of my controller. I want to pass those argument in the args of g:message tag in my gsp page.

Like

```
<g:message code="test.pricing.essentialdetails" args="${[freePages,currencySymbol,periodicFee]}"/>
```

My messages.properties has the below entry

```
test.pricing.essentialdetails=provides {0} pages and is just {1} {2} per month.
```

How to pass multiple arguments in g:message in gsp page?

Comment: What error do you get? Replace the arguments with constants and see how it behaves. Minimize the scope of debugging. BTW, the above setup works great, check whether the arguments are appropriately populated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to pass args as list `args="[freePages,currencySymbol,periodicFee]"`

And final:

```
<g:message code="test.pricing.essentialdetails" args="[freePages,currencySymbol,periodicFee]"/>
```